# Getting checked button in dynamically generated RadioGroup in a fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, radio-button, fragment, radio-group

we have a project that has multiple programmatically generated RadioGroups inside fragments.
the fragment class is like this:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {
private LinearLayout parentLayout;
private View rview;
private Button next;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    generateViews(rview);
    return rview;
}

private void generateViews(View mView) {
    parentLayout = mView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    next = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.next);

    radioGroup = addRadioButton(3);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Radio button id: " + radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        }
    });
}

public RadioGroup addRadioButton(int count) {
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this.getContext());
    radioGroup.setId(View.generateViewId());
    radioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    parentLayout.addView(radioGroup);

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this.getContext());
        radioButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
        radioButton.setText("Radio " + i);
        Log.e("TAG", "Cretaed radio button id: " + radioButton.getId());
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }

    return radioGroup;
}
}
```

when running the project radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() always shows -1.

the code is as simple as it could be.
what i've tried is:

- while generating the radioButtons i also check if it has an id, and it has. so the method View.generateViewId() is working fine.
- changing the parameters in initializing my dynamic RadioGroup and RadioButton's to use the activity context and that didn't affect the result
- iterating through the children of the RadioGroup and check every RadioButton if .isChecked() is true or not, and it showed that no RadioButton is checked.
- some answers for similar questions said that the rView should be global, we have tried that too.

logcat:

```
E/TAG: Cretaed radio button id: 10
E/TAG: Cretaed radio button id: 11
E/TAG: Cretaed radio button id: 12
E/TAG: Cretaed radio button id: 14
E/TAG: Cretaed radio button id: 15
E/TAG: Cretaed radio button id: 16
E/TAG: Radio button id: -1
```

as shown in this logcat log, the log when the RadioButtons are created is showing the ids. and also when next button clicked the getCheckedRadioButtonId returns -1.

anybody have an idea what i'm doing wrong?